# Changing the variable given in a function statement

Tags: python, error-checking

My code so far is:

```
def errorCheckInt(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
        checkValue1 = True
    except:
        checkValue1 = False
```

It is supposed to take a variable input (which is n) and change it to an integer if possible. It will try to get a different input if it is a string.

However, it hasn't worked, and I think it's because you can't change the variable in the code.

This may not be very clear, so I'm giving an example:

```
testingNum = "2"
# def errorCheckInt here

errorCheckInt(testingNum)
# Should change testingNum to integer value 2, not string "2"
```

This would be followed by a while statement, checking whether it was successful (whether checkValue1 is True or False) then possibly asking for a new input and error checking that (depending on the input the user gives).

If this still isn't very clear, just comment a question and I may be able to tell you what I had in mind.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear to me what you mean when you say *"you can't change the variable in the code"*. Honestly, I'm going to take a leap here (since I have no idea where you are at in terms of Python understanding).

There are two concepts I feel like you may be having trouble with. **(1)** is the idea of object mutability, and **(2)** how variables are used and defined in and out of scope inside of Python.

When you re-assign a value like this:

```
n = int(n)
```

You haven't actually modified the value held by the variable outside (`testingNum`). This is because variables in Python are just references to objects. This means that your variable will always point to the same object unless it is re-assigned explicitly. Where this gets confusing is when you're dealing with the concept of **mutability**. For example, lists, dictionaries and classes are mutable objects. If you do something like:

```
t = []
n = t
```

and then do:

```
n.extend([1,2,3,4])
```

you'll see that both `n` and `t` now look like:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

This isn't really mysterious behavior when you finally understand what's going on. The integer `4` and the `[1,2,3,4]` are different objects. The only difference is that `[1,2,3,4]` was also the same object as the initial `[]` when it was assigned to `t`. On the other hand, when you re-assign an integer or a string to a variable, you've simply changed what object the variable is *pointing to*. That's all.

#### How does this apply to your example?

In essence, all you were missing was a `return` statement:

```
def errorCheckInt(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
        checkValue1 = True
    except:
        checkValue1 = False

    return n


testingNum = "2"
newNum = errorCheckInt(testingNum) # You can catch it here with newNum.
```

Understanding the use of the **return** statement is tantamount. When you assign a reference to a variable inside a function, that variable falls out of scope as soon as you exit the function; in other words, if you try to call it afterwards, you'll get an error. To circumvent this, you need to catch the result of your function in a variable that's in the *outer* scope. This allows you to keep working with the data you've just calculated inside the function.

#### Note

A better way of doing what you're asking is to use `isinstance`. For example,

```
print isinstance(4, int)
# True

print isinstance('4', int)
# False
```

This will automatically check if the value is an instance of the `int` type. It's both *clearer and cleaner*.

#### Further clarification

An interesting fact of mutability is that when you pass references to mutable objects inside of functions, modifying the object with, say, `[].append(4)` will mean that any variable pointing to that object (even from outside) is getting the same *update* if you will. So in certain cases using the **return** statement isn't necessary, but being explicit is sometimes worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

When `errorCheckInt` is run, variable `n` is bound to the same value as `testingNum`. However with `n =`, you change the *binding*, not the *value* so `n` then points to a different value than `testingNum`. What you need is to pass a mutable type and change the binding inside it:

```
def errorCheckInt(n):
    try:
        n[0] = int(n[0])
        checkValue1 = True
    except:
        checkValue1 = False

testingNum = [ "2" ]
errorCheckInt(testingNum)
# testingNum is now 2 and type(testingNum) is int
```